# OpenJPA logs in app server console - method printToSystemOut

Tags: logging, openjpa, geronimo

We are using OpenJPA in our application and we are getting the below error trace logs in the application server console.

```
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
addRegisterClassListener + [org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository@2100210] [BEFORE SIZE 3] [AFTER SIZE 4]
java.lang.Throwable
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.printToSystemOut(PCRegistry.java:85)
        at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PCRegistry.addRegisterClassListener(PCRegistry.java:63)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:641)
```

1. The OpenJPA logs are configured to route all trace logs to a application specific log file.
   However these logs are still going to the appserver console logs.
2. Also I'm not able to find out the method printTpSystemOut in PCRegistry class of openJPA source.

What could be the issue here? Or Am I missing something very obvious in this trace.

Comment: What version of OpenJPA are you using?

Comment: 1.2.2 version of openJPA

Comment: I looked through the source for 1.2.2 and I don't see that method call. I also looked through earlier versions tags/branches and I don't see it there either. I'm going to guess that you are running something that was hacked up, or it is really(really) old. I'd advise downloading the latest 1.2.2 from the OpenJPA website.

Comment: I checked the same with the version 1.2.2 from openJPA site and figured out that method call is not even there, however the library used in our geronimo server, seems to be having that method when i extracted the jar to view the method signatures. Not sure, probably someone modified the library or some versions of geronimo shipped with these changes.

Comment: I recall working with someone in this very area a long time back, and these debug statements seem like they could have been used to diagnose a problem. I'd suggest getting rid of this library and reloading from a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the OpenJPA binary in your server with one from the [OpenJPA downloads page](http://openjpa.apache.org/downloads.html).